# Get laravels session auth via ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have laravel 5.4 running with passport. Which is realy nice.
My question is now how can I get the acces token for my ajax calls?

What works is this

```
<script>
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJK..."
            },
            url: '/api/records/',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("yay");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

What have I to do to NOT hardcode the bearer token?
Or what to do better? Is this the right approach? 
Is there a magic method where I can get the session and use the session to auth a user?
 Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you perform the authorization initially, store the token in either your Local Storage, or in a Cookie. The cookie is probably the more secure method, but either way, yea, that's what you do. Then you can reference the cookie or localStore key whenever you want to perform an ajax query.

Comment: You can use the implicit grant token. This way, your application can dynamically request a token. Then store it in local storage.

Comment: if you're calling on same server as your API, then you can just do [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).